# External Display and Blurry Fonts on El Capitan

Tags: terminal, display, font, macos

I am one of the many who have extremely blurry fonts on external displays connected to my 2014 MacBook Pro. The solution for me has always been to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/bastibense/6549835) guide which runs a ruby script and puts the result in an overrides folder.

EDIT: By turning off the new "rootless" feature of El Capitan I was able to gain access to the overrides folder, however it does not appear to have worked. Anyone had any luck fixing the blurry fonts on external displays for El Capitan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the `Overrides` directory changed to `/System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/`. Note that you will need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://gist.github.com/djtech42/7233c602fda912d96fdf) to add files there.

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm for those that find this that the old Overrides folder does not work, however, going through the normal process and moving the created folder to the one above does indeed work.

Comment: No need to disable SIP, just do it in Recovery mode. See: http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor/comment-page-11#comment-14866

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to check whether the monitor in question is already using RGB before the above is attempted as it may not achieve any benefit. To check: Utilities/System Information->Displays and look to see if it is using RGB (You can also check in System Preferences->Displays-> Color->Open Profile->Header->Space) if so then your problem lies elsewhere.

Another possible solution is to try altering Font smoothing options in System Preferences->General'. Or if you're seeing problems in a particular app - e.g. In Preview go to Preferences->PDF and untick 'Smooth text and line art'.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience it was caused by the HDMI connection. I replaced it with a DisplayPort adapter and the problem is solved.

The display auto settings must be different when it detects HDMI and can't find the right parameters for some reason.